# Referencing an object's keys in a property from another property

Tags: typescript

I'm sure this is simpler than I think but I really haven't found anything. It's easier to explain with a simple scenario:

```js
const cookbook: CookBook = {
    ingredients: {
        "tomato": { vegetal: true },
        "cheese": { vegetal: false },
        "lettuce": { vegetal: true },
    },

    recipes: {
        "pizza": ["tomato", "cheese"],
        "salad": ["tomato", "lettuce"]
    }
}

type CookBook = {
    ingredients: {[key: string]: {vegetal: boolean}},
    recipes: {[key: string]: string[]}
}
```

You can see that in the recipes property, the values ​​represent lists of ingredients, which are mere strings. How could I indicate that those strings should be a key of the ingredients object?

```js
    ...
    recipes: {
        // This should not be valid because "pineapple" 
        // is not a key in ingredients property.
        "pizza": ["tomato", "cheese", "pineapple"],
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a function with a generic parameter

```js
const cookbook = createCookBook({
    ingredients: {
        "tomato": { vegetal: true },
        "cheese": { vegetal: false },
        "lettuce": { vegetal: true },
    },

    recipes: {
        "pizza": ["tomato", "cheese"],
        "salad": ["tomato", "lettuce"]
    }
})
```

```js
const createCookBook =
    <T extends CookBook & IsValidCookBook<T>>
        (cookbook: Narrow<T>) => cookbook

type IsValidCookBook<T extends CookBook> = {
    ingredients: T['ingredients'],
    recipes: { [K in keyof T['recipes']]: (keyof T['ingredients'])[] }
}

type Narrow<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]
    : K extends keyof [] ? T[K]
    : T[K] extends (...args: any[]) => unknown ? T[K]
    : Narrow<T[K]>
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBMBOBTAhlRBhEIDWAhL2MAvDADwAqMiAHmmACYQyY744wBkMAkhAGrIANgEt6LPAQoA+KQApQOAEYEAXDAByyePBAB3aQEpiUuAWU4AUBagBPAA6Ie-IaPFtsFKrUQMmbgiYkAN4WMGEwwmAA5kj0wj5QEGrkANoA5JExiHEJEGkAugA0oeFIwMIOSTBBMCkA0hFgMNiINiAAZjCpaWUViHn5+WqyLW2d3Zmx8WCJBQYp+TAAvhYr1vaO-uzBJWGT2dOJakEpo2rQ8JlD1QBuiFGIUEJq5oIoYEtLxeEwvZXHp1a5ygl2i1yQyHo4EENhgF0yCxWa1sDg0Wh0+nIgWqJXqjWarQ6XXyuxgagaNDojAJY1qiwA-F16iSfslmV4qUxZAA6XlaKJVZBgGwLIxEEwAVzA2DAeiajNSdRZ4TUmm0egozKkqwA3FZQJBYApsOZCCQECg0FtsLIQj99jkZlU7T9wgAiKAgAC2qBAbuOMDuDyegjUIIlji+pJ+buAAAtEP1EP7qoH7o9njB2kIIJHvq6wm63lAoBLgMmA0GM6GYOG86So6S-v1jtH3XZhAAvTvIFMpD3e31uwowWMJpNuoptwsQISQvsDn2e4ej4ul8uThurAxAA)

We are constructing a valid `ValidCookBook` object based of the inferred `Cookbook` object and comparing the two. This enables a good developer experience in the IDE.

`Narrow` is used to prevent TS from widening the ingredients array in the recipes, although there are probably cleaner ways to do it now.

---

The type-level alternative looks like this

```js
const cookbook = {
    ingredients: {
        "tomato": { vegetal: true },
        "cheese": { vegetal: false },
        "lettuce": { vegetal: true },
    },

    recipes: {
        "pizza": ["tomato", "cheese"],
        "salad": ["tomato", "lettuce"]
    }
} as const;

{type Test = ValidateCookBook<typeof cookbook>}
```

```js
type ValidateCookBook <T extends CookBook & IsValidCookBook<T>> = never;

type IsValidCookBook<T extends CookBook> = {
    ingredients: T['ingredients'],
    recipes: { [K in keyof T['recipes']]: readonly (keyof T['ingredients'])[] }
}

type CookBook = {
    ingredients: {[key: string]: {vegetal: boolean}},
    recipes: {[key: string]: readonly string[]}
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwJYBM7AgYQPbYNYBCueUAPACpQQAeGAdigM5Q75H5QBkUAko-MhStCxCgD4xUALxQ6EAG4QATgG4AUGtCRe-RKmHs8FKrQgNmB4pJkBvNVAdQkdAOZKIKJGeCMAXFHIAbQByZzcPLzofYIBdABp7R3cAYyRIPygbKECAaSc6KDwIEGwAMwCQlLSIRliY-3c4FGw6BBAoAAoikvKg0Nd3T29amIBKQJioAF81Gc1waEsOW0SHMMHIn38bQO7-RmAlMPrMxRcIYER-ACNcBAg4OimphMcoKvTt3eL9w+OGh7NVrtA5HVwTGZzZItA5QaH4W7LTKrfLhIZRDJ2N5vABEwGwAFt0NgcdsoGcLlcoIcAK7QF4o3HJAAWEBqEFJmXJEHOlwQ-lKiEY9Ne2IcOPuwGANOSHLJFL5-lpIpRDJRHxq20ZjhxYCQAC99XBOYE8YTiTi4lAcSy2cKcfFteLGIgmiazUT8ZbrZLpbKHarZlA4MxoXQDhobFpoOQasBpLA9GgMEsjNGynDiIi8GIpkA)

Comment: The idea of ​​write code that exists at runtime (as in this case a function) just to define typing rules is something that seems inconceivable to me. Also, what happens if we want to establish typing on an already written code? Thank you very much in any case. I will continue investigating. PD: thank you too for the narrow idea, I have found it useful to solve another unrelated problem.

Comment: I can write up a type-level alternative which people tend to hate just as much ;) I understand your concern but I'm pretty sure and identity function such as this one is going to be optimised away by the JIT. If your concern is performance you can also write a transformer plugin that will inline it.

Comment: I like the type level answer, and it solves my problem. I think I have overestimated (or underestimated?) TypeScript. I really felt that what I was proposing was something extremely simple and common to solve in TS, and now I see that it is not something trivial.

Comment: Sadly you are going to feel that way pretty often in TS